# Using forEach on empty array

Tags: javascript, programming-practices

I have a dynamic array that can often be empty, and I need to iterate over all its elements.

So far I have such code:

```
array.forEach(function(item, index) {
    //stuff here
});
```

It works fine of course, but I wonder if there is any overhead for the forEach method when the array is empty, in such case maybe better checking first, e.g.

```
if (array.length > 0) {
    array.forEach(function(item, index) {
        //stuff here
    });
}
```

Which is better practice?

Comment: That's micro-optimization.  I would avoid it.  It has a cost; the developer coming after you is going to ask "why did he put that there?"  If you were in a very tight performance-sensitive loop, or you had run a profiler, then I might consider it, but you aren't, and you didn't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It might even be a micro-pessimisation. I prefer the first version anyhow, "For each of these zero items" doesn't bother me

Comment: @RobertHarvey and you add the overhead of checking the length every time this code executes.  Even if this is an effective micro-optimization (which I doubt) it only helps if the array is often empty.

Comment: the second option only makes sense if we were checking nulls.

Comment: @JimmyJames actually yes, the code runs over many arrays, around 100, and in practice about 90% of them are empty. It probably doesn't change anything though.

Answer (score 2):

In practice it will depend on the JavaScript executor how it handles it.

The check should effectively be done by the `forEach` as it has to check for the end in some way, anyway so you are duplicating the check for an empty array and adding its (minimal) overhead for non-empty ones. So, you are probably adding extra CPU cycles.

In general, only do this type of change if a profiler has indicated that a lot of time is spent on the operation.